# how to generate endless random objects in corona SDK?

Tags: random, lua, coronasdk

so I am very new to coding in general and I am trying to make a vertically-scrolling endless runner which basically involves jumping onto platforms to stay alive.I want to generate the same platform in three different locations endlessly. I basically copied some code from an article on the internet and then changed it around to try to make it suit my needs. However, when I run my code in the simulator, one platform is generated in the same location and no others appear. Also, when I look at the console, random numbers do appear. here is the code I am using

```
local blocks = display.newGroup ()
local groundMin = 200
local groundMax = 100
local groundLevel = groundMin

local function blockgenerate( event )
for a = 1, 1, -1 do
isDone = false

numGen = math.random(3)
local newBlock
print (numGen)
if (numGen == 1 and isDone == false) then
newBlock = display.newImage ("platform.jpg")
end

if (numGen == 2 and isDone == false) then
newBlock = display.newImage ("platform.jpg")
end

if (numGen == 3 and isDone == false) then
newBlock = display.newImage ("platform.jpg")
end

newBlock.name = ("block" .. a)
newBlock.id = a

 newBlock.x = (a * 100) - 100
 newBlock.y = groundLevel
 blocks : insert(newBlock)
 end
 end
 timer.performWithDelay (1000, blockgenerate, -1)
```

thank you very much in advance and sorry my description was so long

Comment: Please include a screenshot of the log, which numbers are being generated?

Answer (score 0):

Your "a" variable is always going to be 1.  Perhaps you meant to use:

a = a + 1